# Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to create an App Service web app in the Azure Portal and to connect the web app to my local on-premises SQL Server database using the new Hybrid Connection feature.

Created a simple ASP.NET application using Visual Studio 2015 and trying to connect to the SQL server Database which is on on-prem. And modified the connection String as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=PRAVEEN,1433; User ID=sa; Password=my_password;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When the application is started its running without any errors as shown in below screenshot1.

But when I try register (enter any record) it throws me with an error as specified in the below Screenshot3....

"https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server/" - this is the documentation to which I'm referring to..

So, can anyone from the other end help me out please...

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: ScreenShot2]

[image: Screenshot3]

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio screenshot....

[image: Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio]

Thank you..

Comment: Are you able to connect in SQL Management studio with same credentials?

Comment: ha, its working with same credentials from SQL management studio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Praveen,
It is what it says - meaning Initial Catalog is missing in your connection string. It requires the Db name to connect to. You have the servername, SQLUserName, SQLPassword, but missing the `DatabaseName` it requires. Please change your connection string to include the the DbName as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=YourServerName,1433;Database="YourDbName" UserID=YourId;Password=YourPswd;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Look at this site to configure your connection string appropriately: http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/

Comment: Build errors? Can you update the question with these errors. Also can you let us know if you are using asp.net core or asp.net 4.5? Cause this can make a difference as well

Comment: Error parsing the web configuration file at line 13 . Whitespace expected

Comment: What do you have at line 13 in your config file - looks like you have a malformed connectionstring, try substituting the word `IntialCatalog` with `Database`  and try connecting. Also look at the updated link in my answer, it will help you configure your connection string

Comment: I have tried with the connection string which u have provided.. still same error

Comment: At line number 13 i'm having my connection string information

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=PRAVEEN,1433;Intial Catalog ="database_name" UserID=sa;Password=my_password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=PRAVEEN,1433;Initial Catalog =My_DataBase_Name; User ID=sa;Password=My_Passoword; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>